# Otimização de hiperparâmetros de uma ESN com o Keras Tuner

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Preciso fazer uma otimização Bayesiana dos hiperparâmetros da minha Echo State Network (ESN). Para isso, estou utilizando o [Keras Tuner](https://keras.io/api/keras_tuner/tuners/bayesian/) e a ESN do [Tensorflow Addons](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/layers/ESN).

Montei o seguinte modelo:

```
def criar_modelo(hp):
    model = Sequential(name='ESN_NE')
    model.add(InputLayer((57, 1), name='camada_entrada'))
    model.add(ESN(units=hp.Int('units', min_value=100, max_value=500, step=50),
                  connectivity=hp.Float('connectivity', min_value=0.1, max_value=0.4, step=0.1),
                  spectral_radius=hp.Float('spectral_radius', min_value=0.5, max_value=0.9, step=0.1),
                  activation=hp.Choice('activation_esn', ['relu', 'tanh', 'sigmoid']),
                  name='camada_esn'))
    # model.add(Flatten())
    if hp.Boolean('dropout'):
        model.add(Dropout(rate=hp.Float('rate', min_value=0.2, max_value=0.5, step=0.1)))

    for k in range(hp.Int('num_layers', 1, 2)):
        model.add(Dense(units=hp.Int(f'units_{k}', min_value=24, max_value=120, step=24),
                        activation=hp.Choice('activation_dense', ['relu', 'tanh', 'sigmoid']),
                        name=f'{k}_dense'))
    model.add(Dense(units=24,
                    activation=hp.Choice('activation_out', ['relu', 'tanh', 'sigmoid']),
                    name='camada_saida'))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='mean_squared_error')
    return model
```

Porém, estou obtendo o seguinte erro no momento de começar a busca pelos hiperpâmetros:

```
Search: Running Trial #1
Value             |Best Value So Far |Hyperparameter
200               |?                 |units
0.3               |?                 |connectivity
0.6               |?                 |spectral_radius
tanh              |?                 |activation_esn
False             |?                 |dropout
1                 |?                 |num_layers
72                |?                 |units_0
sigmoid           |?                 |activation_dense
relu              |?                 |activation_out
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Muril\PycharmProjects\tf-gpu\venv\lib\site-packages\keras_tuner\engine\tuner.py", line 158, in _try_build
    model = self._build_hypermodel(hp)
  File "C:\Users\Muril\PycharmProjects\tf-gpu\venv\lib\site-packages\keras_tuner\engine\tuner.py", line 146, in _build_hypermodel
    model = self.hypermodel.build(hp)
  File "<ipython-input-7-037106db3086>", line 4, in criar_modelo
    model.add(ESN(units=hp.Int('units', min_value=100, max_value=500, step=50),
  File "C:\Users\Muril\PycharmProjects\tf-gpu\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py", line 629, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Muril\PycharmProjects\tf-gpu\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\Muril\PycharmProjects\tf-gpu\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_addons\rnn\esn_cell.py", line 159, in build
    self.recurrent_kernel = self.add_weight(
  File "C:\Users\Muril\PycharmProjects\tf-gpu\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_addons\rnn\esn_cell.py", line 151, in _esn_recurrent_initializer
    scaling_factor = tf.math.divide_no_nan(
ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype float64 for Tensor with dtype float32: <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.55648464>
```

Pelo que vi do erro, ele ocorre na linha 4 da minha função `criar_modelo(hp)`, ou seja, `model.add(ESN(units=hp.Int('units', min_value=100, max_value=500, step=50)`. Essa linha é onde defino o número de neurônios da minha ESN, que são valores `Int`. Porém o erro remete a `Float64` e `Float32`. Não entendi muito bem... o que fiz de errado?

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: O erro remete a linha 4 da minha função. Nessa linha eu defino o número de neurônios da minha ESN, que deve ser um `int`. Porém o erro mostrado é referente a `float64` e `float32`. Não ficou claro para mim o porque, ou como resolver isso. Pois de fato não posso mudar aquele parâmetro `units` para `float`, ele deve ser `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Entrei em contato com os responsáveis do [Tensorflow Addons](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons), e encontramos um erro no código que criava a célula da ESN. Segue o link do PR feito no Github para correção do erro.

https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/pull/2793

Basicamente, no arquivo `esn_cell.py`, deve-se trocar o `self.spectral_radius` por `tf.cast(self.spectral_radius, dtype)` nas linhas `146`e `152`.